# Why is python not recognizing when a string is in a file

Tags: python, file

I am making a pretend login system as a project. When the in_file variable is in the file I want it to print you are logged in. However, it doesn't do this since it doesn't think that the in_file variable is in the file. How do I fix this?

sample of the file

username/password

Matthew/06112004

James/Nemo20044!

```
account = input('do you want to sign up or login ? ')
file = open('login.txt', 'a+')

def log_in(filename):
    logging_in = True
    while logging_in:
        username = input('Username: ')
        password = input('Password: ')
        in_file = f'{username}/{password}'
        if in_file in filename.read():
            print('you are logged in')
            logging_in = False
        if in_file not in filename.read():
            print('user name or password are incorrect')

if account == 'login':
    log_in(file)
```

Comment: You want to open the file in read mode, `file = open('login.txt', 'r')` and then your other problem is that you can only read a file once. Save the read call to a variable and then query the variable instead.

Comment: Also required watching!!! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Comment: Did my post answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file with the `'r'`(read) mode, the `'a'` mode will only let you *append* to the file.

So change `file = open('login.txt', 'a+')` to `file = open('login.txt', 'r')`.

Note that it is not a very good practice to `open()` and `close()` a file. Instead, use a [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).